# Setting default time in grails rich ui's dateChooser

Tags: grails, plugins, default-value, rich-ui

I want to set the default time in grails rich ui plugin's dateChooser feature.

richui:dateChooser name="fromdate" value="${old?.fromdate}"
format="dd.MM.yyyy"  time="true"/>

I get the default time to be 00.00, How to set the default time an date if I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no default setting for time right now in dateChooser .

you could modify the plugin or add some javascript to drop in a default time